# Error: Junk at end of line -as and -o error with ARM

Tags: arm, putty, machine-code

I am attempting to write my first ARM program and getting this error when I try to run
"as -o labl1.o lab1.s"

```
lab1.s:3: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `s'
```

I am very unsure about what I am doing wrong here, as the only times I use s is in my 2 strings, and very puzzled on where in the code I went wrong.

```
@Data
.data
string1: .asciz
string2: .asciz

@Code
.text
.global main
.extern printf

main:

push {ip, lr}

push {r0, r1, r2}
ldr r0, =string1
mov r1, #34
mov r2, #56
bl printf
pop {r0,r1,r2}

push {r0}
ldr r0, =string2
bl printf
pop {r0}

pop {ip, pc}
```

Links to helpful documents or help debugging would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be confusing the address of your strings and the values you want to assign them: As specified in GNU as [documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Asciz.html#Asciz), the `.asciz` directive does require a string argument - a slightly modified version of your code does assemble correctly:

```
.data
string1: .asciz "string1"
string2: .asciz "string2"
```

`string1` is now the label for the address where bytes `"string1\x00`" are located, and `string2` is the label for the address where bytes `"string2\x00"` are.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Assigning the strings with that method allowed me to change my code from assembly to machine, however running " gcc -o lab1 lab1.o " is giving me (.text+0x30) and (.text+0x34) errors, telling me I have undefined references to my strings 1 & 2. Any ideas on where I'd be going wrong here?

Comment: My pleasure. By the way, if the answer was helpful, you may accept it, it would be apreciated. I was unable to reproduce your issue, even though the linker complained as expected about missing  `_start` and `_printf` symbols.