# Assembly Compilation failed dued to unrecognized character

Tags: assembly, compilation, arm

I am here to describe you my problem.
I have a project in assembly and I have to compile it in order to catch instructions to convert and recall on Forth.

The istruction that I have to execute is:

```
arm-eabi-none delay.s -o delay.o
```

in order to bring object file and execute the objectDump.

The problem is that the execution give me this problem:

```
delay.s: Assembler messages:
delay.s: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted
delay.s:1: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is G'
```

I report my entire code here in order to show you what I have done, cause I really don't understand this error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r87jk.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BieOk.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhRYP.png

Comment: You have to post your code in text.

Comment: Yes, as pointed out by the tool none of those opening lines of the code are valid in any asm I have ever seen...much less gnu assembler or gcc which we cannot tell because of your invalid command line.

Comment: read the output of the tool and follow what it says.  first unrecognized character is G'

Comment: since you are using gnu assembler or gcc preprocessed gnu assembler (different language) you at least need to read the gnu assembler documentation (as assembly is specific to the tool not the target).  (hint:  .equ)

Comment: and going forward do not post images of code, post the code, a minimal reproducable amount.  Also post the actual command line against the code you prepared for this question.  So paste in 100% of the code required to cause the problem and a real command line as well as the output from the tool.  In some cases the version of the tool is useful.

Comment: @old_timer GNU assembler accepts that kind of assignment. See the [manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Setting-Symbols.html): "a symbol, followed by an equals sign ‘=’, followed by an expression. This is equivalent to using the .set directive. ".

Comment: apparently not as the error message indicates.  although the question is incomplete so we cannot know the exact problem.

Comment: We don't know what assembler Martina is using. I was just replying to your _"none of those opening lines of the code are valid in any asm I have ever seen"_. I have GNU assembler (GNU Binutils) 2.33.1 and the assignments work fine.

Comment: I wondered if perhaps the space between the symbol and the = was the problem, but GNU Binutils for x86 accepts `x =1` without complaint.  Also, your error message cites line 1, which has no space.

Comment: Have you checked for a DOS or Mac vs. Unix line-ending problem?  Like perhaps you only have classic Mac newlines (0xD = CR with no line-feed) so the assembler thinks everything is on one line?  Your pictures of text are not helpful for determining this or anything else.  But copy/paste as text wouldn't help with that either.

Comment: There are many causes of this issue.  One possible cause I see is `GPFSEL2=0x3F200008` and `ldr r0,GPFSEL2` (also Jake's answer).  This [pseudo-op](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Opcodes.html#ARM-Opcodes) is generally used with labels.  Also, there are more modern forms. [ARM constant blog](https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/processors/b/processors-ip-blog/posts/how-to-load-constants-in-assembly-for-arm-architecture).  If you can minimize the code and post the result, it would be possible to determine the cause.

Comment: Also [Error junk at end of line...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60104371/error-junk-at-end-of-line-as-and-o-error-with-arm)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
.equ    GPFSEL2,    0x3f200008
.equ    GPSET0,     0x3f20001c
.equ    GPCLR0,     0x3f200028
.equ    GPLEV0,     0x3f200034
.equ    SYSTIMER_CLO,   0x3f003004
.
.
. your code here
.
.
.end
```

Answer (score 2):

**Perhaps your line-endings don't match what the assembler is expecting**, so the assembler thinks everything is on one line?  That could explain the error messages.  (It's perhaps not the only possible explanation, though.)

For example, putting `x =1   y =2` in `foo.s` and assembling it with GNU binutils `as` gives exactly that error message:

```
foo.s:1: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `y'
```

But with those assemble-time constants defined on separate lines, it works.  (Even with the space before the `=`, so that's not the problem).

(Note that the 2nd source line in your image also starts with `G`, so the error message doesn't help distinguish this from an unprintable hidden character on the actual first line.)

Have you checked for a DOS or Mac vs. Unix line-ending problem?  Perhaps you have Unix line-endings but you're running a Windows version of `as`, and it somehow discards a single `\n` LF (0xa) in text-mode input?  Or whatever is doing line-oriented input is actually looking for a CR LF pair (`\r\n`)?

That would also explain the `Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted`.

---

Your pictures of text are not helpful for determining this or anything else.  But copy/paste as text wouldn't help with that either.  You could check by looking at a hexdump of your source file.

You could also simplify the question by creating a [MCVE] with just the first 2 lines.  You just need something that should assemble but doesn't; it doesn't have to *do* anything.

Comment: "a CF LF pair" Wording mistake, you meant CR.

Comment: @ecm: thanks, fixed.

Comment: At the end the problem is simply some constant that wasn't instantiated thank you all